# How to fix redirects in nginx after the front-slash in the end of the URL

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-301

We are changing our web from example.se to example.com and also changing a few categories from Swedish to English so I need to point the old URLs to new ones with new names.

I am trying to redirect example.se/something to example.com/anything-else

I've managed to accomplish the redirection from example.se > example.com but whenever I try to go to example.com/something > example.com/anything-else I get a 404.

Here's the nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name example.se www.example.se;

    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://.example.com/$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^/something/$ /anything-else/ permanent;
}
```

What I've managed to accomplish is the redirection from example.se > example.com but whenever I try to go to example.com/something (which I'd like to point to example.com/anything-else) I get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

In second redirect you should specify domain name: `rewrite ^/something/$ http://example.com/anything-else/ permanent` instead `rewrite ^/something/$ /anything-else/ permanent`

Or you could use **if**:

```
if ($request_uri  =  / )  {
          rewrite (.*) http://example.com/ permanent;
      }
if ($request_uri ~ ^/something) {
          rewrite (.*) http://example.com/anything-else permanent;
      }
```

Comment: I added the one with *if*

But when I go to example.se/something I land on example.com/something instead of example.com/anything-else

And when I tried the full URL I got a 404 aswell.

Comment: @Phlaryu So, your config look like this now? :

`server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name example.se www.example.se;

    if ($request_uri  =  / )  {
              rewrite (.*) http://example.com/ permanent;
          }
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/something) {
              rewrite (.*) http://example.com/anything-else permanent;
          }
}`

Comment: Ah!
I misstyped, that works!! But I get a ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in chrome when trying to go to example.se, however www.example.se redirects without a warning.